# navigation stack error

Tags: ros, navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I launch navigation launch file with all the parameters and when i press the 2D pose estimate in rviz i get this error :

```
 Ignoring initial pose in frame "odom"; initial poses must be in the global frame, "map"
```

I don't really know what it means and i don't why is this happening . Do you need any of the param files to investigate  this error ? let me know .

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/408190/navigation-stack-error/) by [Kostas Tzias](https://answers.ros.org/users/108968/kostas-tzias/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2022-10-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This question with its answers seems to be connected:

- https://answers.ros.org/question/81836/intialpose-is-in-what-reference/

> [Initial pose in RVIZ] is being sent in the frame that you set as the fixed frame in rviz.

and

> The pose sent is in reference to the fixed frame in RVIZ - and therefore, you should almost certainly have your fixed frame set to `/map` as AMCL is determining the transform from `base_link->odom->map`, and the pose you send should be where `base_link` is in terms of map (so that the `initial_odom->map transform` can be determined)

Can you check your fixed frame in RViz?
[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-10-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0